# Sitecore Web Forms for Marketers and DMS - not recording campaigns, goals and dropout info

Tags: sitecore, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-dms

In WFFM there is an option so that, when someone abandons the form, any data that was entered in the form itself is recorded and should be accessible via the Dropout Report.

I have a WFFM for which I have turned on Analytics and turned on the dropout feature. Unfortunately I don't see any data being recorded in the DB and the Dropout Report is visible, but empty.

I see from the javascript code included in the WFFM folder that a series of AJAX calls are supposed to save the fields on blur events -- with calls to /sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Tracking.aspx

I tried debugging the Javascript code, but the method supposed to post the info to /sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Tracking.aspx is never being called. Can you think of any reasons for this code not to work? Also, does anyone know which table this information is supposed to be recorded? Is it the fields table in the WFFM DB?

Finally, even though I have turned on analytics on this particular WFFM form and I have associated a campaign and a goal to the submission of the form, none of these is being recorded. I see that the data entered in the form is stored successfully and is displaying in the Data Report, but no info about the Campaign nor the Goal are recorded in the DB.

I even checked manually directly in the DMS DB running:

```
select top 10
p.DateTime, p.UrlText, cp.CampaignName
,i.Url, vi.VisitId
from pages p
inner join ItemUrls i on p.ItemId = i.ItemId
inner join Visits vi on vi.VisitId = p.VisitId
inner join GeoIps g on vi.Ip = g.Ip
left join Campaigns cp on cp.CampaignId = vi.CampaignId
order by p.DateTime desc
```

This one shows that the page where the form is rendered is being hit, but no campaign is associated to the visit.

Then I tried the following:

```
select pe.datetime, ped.Name, pg.UrlText from PageEvents pe
inner join PageEventDefinitions ped on ped.PageEventDefinitionId = pe.PageEventDefinitionId
inner join Pages pg on pg.PageId = pe.PageId
order by pe.DateTime desc
```

But I don't see any entry for this particular campaign nor for the goal (while I see entries for other campaigns and goals associated to non-WFFM Sitecore items)

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Francesco

**EDIT**

The sc.webform.js file contains this method:

```
_create: function () {
var self = this,
    options = this.options;
if (options.tracking) {
    this.element.find("input[type!='submit'], select, textarea")
    .bind('focus', function (e) { self.onFocusField(e, this) })
    .bind('blur change', function (e) { self.onBlurField(e, this) });

    this.element.find("select")
        .change(function () { $scw.webform.controls.updateAnalyticsListValue(this) });

    this.element.find("input[type='checkbox'], input[type='radio']")
        .click(function () { $scw.webform.controls.updateAnalyticsListValue(this) });
}

this.element.find(".scfDatePickerTextBox").each(function () { $scw.webform.controls.datePicker(this) });
},
```

This is supposed to be called by the form on sc.webform widget initialization. It should bind the focus and blur change events for all input fields, drop downs and text areas. Unfortunately, when I tried to put a break point inside this method, it never gets called.

**SECOND EDIT**

Interesting. I figured out that the whole thing should start from this line of Javascript code embedded in the page that contains the WFFM form:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$scwhead.ready(function() {
    $scw('#form_A8BF483419174F97A2830E12CBCF7E4F').webform({formId: "{A8BF4834-1917-4F97-A283-0E12CBCF7E4F}",pageId: "{21C24144-B964-4FBA-8388-D9B90EBBC17C}",eventCountId: "pagecolumns_0_columncontent_0_bottomrow_0_form_A8BF483419174F97A2830E12CBCF7E4F_form_A8BF483419174F97A2830E12CBCF7E4F_eventcount",tracking: true})
}); 
</script>
```

Once I put a break point here, I was finally able to trace into the _create method of the jQuery.UI widget defined in sc.webform.js. The code that calls _create is actually inside the jQuery.UI library. Kinda makes sense, right?

Finally, the code inside **_create** is executed, the blur events are bound to the **TrackEvents** method, also defined within the widget:

```
_trackEvents: function(events) {
$scw.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: "/sitecore modules/web/Web Forms for Marketers/Tracking.aspx" + location.search,
     data: {track: JSON.stringify(events)},
     dataType: 'json'
});
```

What doesn't make sense is that now, even though I can finally see trackEvents being called whenever I tab from field to field in the WFFM form (why wasn't working before it's a mistery to me), I don't see any data recorded in the WFFM DB. I even tried a quick query in the DB:

```
select f.Timestamp, f.StorageName, fi.Value, fi.FieldName 
from Form f
inner join Field fi on f.Id = fi.FormId
order by f.Timestamp desc, FieldName
```

Does anybody know where is Tracking.aspx supposed to save the captured field informations?

Comment: Did you install the WFFM module correctly? Can you confirm DMS itself is working via the analytics reports?

Comment: Mark, DMS 2.0 is working fine. If I add campaigns and goals to any other page other than a WFFM form, they get recorded just fine. We have just upgraded from Sitecore 6.2 to 6.5 and installed DMS 2.0 (we used to have OMS but it wasn't used so we essentially installed DMS 2.0 from scratch). We have also upgraded WFFM to the latest version. WFFM is working in the sense that it does record content in the DB when a form is submitted and does perform various actions on submit (i.e. save to CRM, etc.). The things that are not working are related to DMS only, at least this is what it seems so far...

Answer (score 1):

This may be silly to ask, but did you configure the data source correctly for your WFFM?  I mean, obviously, you're using WFFM..but is it set to use SQL or is it using the "file" that WFFM uses by default as it's database.

like this to use SQL:

```
   <!-- MSSQL-->

    <formsDataProvider type="Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataProviders.WFMDataProvider,Sitecore.Forms.Core">
  <param desc="connection string">Database=Sitecore_WebForms;Data Source=xxx;user id=xxx;password=xxx;Connect Timeout=30</param>
</formsDataProvider>

<!-- SQLite -->

<!--<formsDataProvider type="Sitecore.Forms.Data.DataProviders.SQLite.SQLiteWFMDataProvider,Sitecore.Forms.Core">
  <param desc="connection string">Data Source=/data/sitecore_webforms.db;version=3;BinaryGUID=true</param>
</formsDataProvider>-->
```

If you don't configure that correctly, I'm wondering if somehow data is being recorded in one place but not another?  Also, another question I have is to ask if this is a dev environment, are you running webforms in live mode?  It just seems to me like this is a configuration issue.

Comment: Like I said above, "I see entries for other campaigns and goals associated to non-WFFM Sitecore items", so yes, the DB is defined correctly in that section of the form.config file.
You may be onto something though. We recently moved the DMS database to a different server. All I changed was the connection string in the Sitecore connectionsStrings.config file... is there another place where I am supposed to change the connection string?

Comment: And, to answer your other question, no I am not running in live mode. I am testing this in a QA environment that has both a CM and a CD server available. In particular I am testing from the CD website.

Answer (score 1):

We are experiencing the exact same problem on 6.5 update 6 and WFFM 2.3.3 rev. 111209. We can see the asynchronous calls to the server including the probably well formed json object containing the correct event.

Example:

```
track:[{"fieldId":"{E0A0BCDD-85E1-4D8D-9E76-5ABD240423C9}","type":"Field Completed","value":"test","formId":"{0F3B57C1-1B6A-43B9-A5A6-2E958C168B31}","pageId":"{025AFF68-62B9-42CE-B49F-0C36311E1976}","ticks":16}]
```

We don't see any of the dropouts arrive in the database, though...

Answer (score 0):

Have you made sure your campaigns and goals have been deployed? If you have switched databases they may not be. To redeploy do this:

1. For each Goal in System -> Marketing Center -> Goals
2. Change the workflow state to draft
3. Save
4. Then in the review ribbon click deploy.
5. This will create an entry in the pageeventdefinition table and allow
   you to query.

Don't forget to do the same for campaigns.